# iOS serial tasks vs gcd

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Having a question about serial tasks and dispatch_queue
my sample is :
have 1101 items to insert into sqlite, I use 'insert into select union all select 'to do the insert job, but sqlite only supports 500 items once, so separate data and insert them one by one,
question is my DB operation model process all sql in a dispatch_queue(a serial queue) and when finish one task using a block to do callback.

so if I wanna do task2 after task1 finished successfully, i can't, because of dispatch queue
any idea or suggestions on this design, or if keep the dispatch queue, what can i do ?

current code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)  //n tasks
{
   do a task in dispatch queue:^(BOOL success){
      if(success)
       do task 2
   }
}
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, taking into account that the queue is serial:

```
__block NSError* _task_error = nil;

for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)  //n tasks
{
   dispatch_async(queue, ^ {
      if(_task_error != nil) return; //There was an error in a previous task - we done.

      //Try performing operation, and on error - set _task_error to hold information on the problem.
   }
}

//Finally, add cleanup operation to log final result.
dispatch_async(queue, ^ {
   //Write to your log here, notify handlers on error, etc.

   //Finally, clean the _task_error so next batch has a clean start.
   _task_error = nil;
}
```

Since the queue is serial and FIFO is guaranteed, the blocks will execute in order and a task would not be attempted if a previous task was not successful.